# Display distinct Badge_ID

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, distinct

This is my query having the Current Results as displayed below.

```
SELECT 
    Distinct CONVERT(int, Employees_1.Emp_Badge_No) AS Emp_Badge_No,
    Employees_1.Emp_LastName, Employees_1.Emp_FirstName, Employees_1.Email,
    Employees_1.NT_Name, Employees_1.Dept_key,
    Employees_1.Emp_LastName + ',' + Employees_1.Emp_FirstName AS FullName,
    dbo.department_vw.DepartmentShortName AS deptname, 
    Employees_1.active_flag
FROM data_common.dbo.employees_union_vw AS Employees_1
INNER JOIN dbo.department_vw
    ON Employees_1.Dept_key = dbo.department_vw.DepartmentKey
```

Sample data:

[image]

I need help to achieve the Expected Results. What will I modify with my existing sql query? 
I want to keep all the records even though it is inactive as long as the Emp_Badge_No is not repeated. I only want those duplicate Emp_Badge_No to be remove.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is exact DBMS you're using? Your question is tagged by both MySQL and SQL Server. Also - what is your exact DB schema (part of it related to question)? From your question it's hard to deduce relations between tables since you're mentioned one table set in question but there is another tables in your query. It will be easier to answer if you will provide some sample data as well as desired result.

Comment: I only want the Emp_Badge_No to be distinct

Comment: `Distinct` keyword is related to the whole query. So you will get all records having distinct `Emp_Badge_No`, `Emp_LastName` and other fields from select list.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: As I've said - `distinct` keyword is related to the whole query. In your case records having 15491 `badge_no` and SAMPLE `last_name` are different in `active_flag` field (one has value 0 and other 1) - so they are distinct.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking how to make it distinct.

Comment: Have you any logic to apply to the current resultset in order to make it expected one? For example, why should active_flag be 0 and not 1 for records having emp_badge_no = 15491 and emp_lastname = SAMPLE? There are both of these values in current resultset, so what is exclusion/filtering criteria?

Comment: can't you understand my point? I only want to make the Emp_Badge_No into unique or distinct regardless if it is active or not or whatsoever.

Comment: Then just throw out all other columns from your query and leave only Emp_Badge_No. It will be guaranteed to be unique. It looks like we're really don't understand each other. I give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `ROW_NUMBER` for this. Modify the `ORDER BY` clause depending on which row from the duplicate entry you want to retrieve:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT 
       e.Emp_Badge_No,
       e.Emp_LastName, 
       e.Emp_FirstName,
       e.Email,
       e.NT_Name, 
       e.Dept_key, 
       e.Emp_LastName + ',' + e.Emp_FirstName AS FullName,
       d.DepartmentShortName AS deptname, 
       e.active_flag,
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.Emp_Badge_No ORDER BY e.Active)
    FROM data_common.dbo.employees_union_vw AS e
    INNER JOIN dbo.department_vw d
        ON e.Dept_key = d.DepartmentKey
)
SELECT
    Emp_Badge_No,
    Emp_LastName, 
    Emp_FirstName,
    Email,
    NT_Name, 
    Dept_key, 
    FullName,
    deptname, 
    active_flag
FROM Cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

The above will get the Inactive record if there are duplicates. If you want to get the Active records instead, replace `rn` with:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Emp_Badge_No ORDER BY e.Active DESC)
```

If you don't care whether it's Active or Inactive, replace `rn` with:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Emp_Badge_No ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
```